# TwiML not working

Tags: php, twilio

We're building Call Tracking website using Twilio API.

The goal of our website is, when someone call a Twilio number (i.e (855) 329-5712), that call will be redirected to a specific predefined number.

The following TwiML we have generated for the same:

```
<Response>
 <Play>//s3.amazonaws.com/calltrackingdashboard/upload/greetings/d9e5234534c5ca818e26225ed7e15809.mp3</Play>
 <Dial record="true">
   <Number url="http://www.filenewtrack.com/callfrds/whisper/170">+919674683063</Number>
 </Dial>
</Response>
```

The Call is not connecting to the receiver properly.
Call just redirecting properly and the Caller heard the continuous ringing though the receiver receives and start communication. Even Call Whisper is not working.

Any help in this regard will be highly obliged.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you looked at your Twilio App Monitor to see what errors (If Any) there are? [https://www.twilio.com/user/account/developer-tools/app-monitor](https://www.twilio.com/user/account/developer-tools/app-monitor)

Answer (score 0):

Twilio evangelist here.

In addition to checking the App Monitor, I'd also suggest checking the [call logs](https://www.twilio.com/user/account/log/calls) and see what Twilio is logging as the result of the call.

It looks like you are trying to dial an Indian number, so if nothing interesting shows up in the call logs or the app monitor, my suggestion would be to drop our awesome support team an email at help@twilio.com.  If possible, include in your email the Call Sids of several calls where you experience the issue so the support team can dig into them for you.

Hope that helps.